# using prototype functions for an array of object literals

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am using PHP, MySQL, and javascript. I use php to connect to my database to select appointments. I then echo them in a script tag as arrays of object literals (JSON objects):

```
appointment[$apptid] = {"time":"8:00", "date":"2012-02-10", "description":"testAppt"};
...
```

I chose to do it this way over writing an appointment "class" in case I add or remove appointment fields, however I can't figure out for the life of me how to create functions that will apply to this array of objects. Is there anyway to declare these as appointment objects and then write prototype functions without losing the properties?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you're after, but if I understand then maybe this is what you want:

First of all, in javascript you better use arrays in a different way than in php, so do something like:

```
var appointments = [];
appointments.push({"time":"8:00", "date":"2012-02-10", "description":"testAppt"});
```

Now, once you the array you can do something like:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert(this.time);
}

for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
    appointments[i].doSomething = doSomething;
}
```

Comment: right but how do I make "doSomething()" only available to appoinments. Issue being that appointments and audits are two different things but both have a "length" (duration of appt or audit) so if I want to use something like updateLength(), I would want it to connect to a different php script depending on what it is (audit or appointment). Obviously I could have two different function names (updateAuditLength() and updateApptLength()) but it doesn't seem like its the right way. I am confusing myself just writing this, I realize trying to read this without knowing anything about the app is hard

Comment: Just add different methods to the different classes.  In your example you had an array of appointments right? so for all the objects in that array you can add some methods, and for the objects in the audits add other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `JSON.parse`: http://www.json.org/js.html

Using this, you can parse your JSON strings into appointment objects that contain your variables as defined in the JSON string, with no prototyped functions.

Then, if you want to get really fancy, you can use the "reviver" parameter to pass in a function in which you could define the functions for each appointment object.

Comment: Yea I really didn't want to use outside libraries.. I am just worried about running into global function pollution.. I have a view audit window and a view appointment window which are displayed when clicking on the element in the calendar, but they share some common attributes like "length" so when I call "populateAndSelectLength()" I would like to call it from an object of appointment or audit type..

Comment: JSON is not an outisde library, most browsers have that implemented.

Comment: Yea the good browsers, but most of the people who will be using the app will be running IE..

Comment: JSON is not an outside library, but Crockford's JavaScript parser/stringifier that I linked technically is. However, you don't have to worry about global function pollution - all of the functions are declared as part of an object called `JSON` (which is used more like a namespace than an object - rather like jQuery). So you call `JSON.parse("JSON STRING GOES HERE")`, etc. The whole library is pretty tiny as well, so that's not an issue, either. It's used all over the web - I really do recommend you at least take a look.

Comment: In addition, as I said before, you could use the `reviver` parameter to generate your populateAndSelectLength() function on the prototype of your appointment object.